# Build libiconv library

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-c++

I want to convert S-JIS string to EUC string. I searched on the internet and find out libiconv library which can do that. I downloaded version 1.9 for windows and did converting.

However, there are some characters which this library can not convert. I also found new version of libiconv 1.13 but there is no library for windows to download, just have source to build.

I tried to build in cygwin and get some files as the below.

libiconv.dll.a
libiconv.la
...

Could you please to guide me to build library.

Thanks,
Ankata

Answer (score 1):

I do not have experience about using libiconv under windows. But it seems that your problem is mainly a compiling problem.
libiconv.dll： the file where libiconv function entrys is stored
libiconv.la : in my opinion, should be a lib file used to link the entry address information to your programm

Besides, these file, you also need the "header" files that libiconv should provide.

You include the header file when you edit your code using libicon, and add the libiconv.la file to your link file list when you compile your code.

If you want run your program, you should put the libiconv.dll under the exe file folder.
As well, if you want to run your program out of cygwin environment, you may also need to copy cygwin1.dll under your exe folder.

Just some suggestion, wish it could help you.